# Can't open an Actionscript project with Flashdevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, flixel

I'm working on creating flash games using actionscript 3, i'm trying to open a Flixel project with FlashDevelop but i can't find a way to do it, i cerated a new project and put the files inside but nothing it seems to work, this is the link for the project on Github :

https://github.com/monday8am/BigHeadFootball_FLA

Answer (score 0):

Although 'nothing seems to work' is a bit of a vague description, you might want to consider the following:
1. When you have put all the files in the FlashDevelop project folder (so that means merging the existing src folder with the one from the project etc.) have you set the Document class correctly?
2. If you've followed step 1 and try to run it, what kind of errors come up? If it can't find certain classes or assets you might have to move these.

Basically, it should be possible to open the project with FD once you've set the correct Document class and merged the two projects correctly.

Comment: .. I replaced all the new FD project contents with the files from the project, and already set the Document class, the project is working great on Flash Builder so i don't think there is a problem with the assets.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the build path to me. What kind of errors do you get when you compile on FD?